# load image file with fileUpload to server and try to read it

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have some problem with subject. My program asks user to load picture with fileUpload and then this file has to show both in listBox as filename and in Image as picture. Everything is done except showing picture in Image control. I've already read a lot of forums and tried to change url with ~ / \ but nothing help. B.t.w., I tried to change access security in properties for folder, but it doesn't still work. That is why, I ask you to help me. This is part of my code which load file and must show it:

```
        string folderPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\images\");
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath + filename);
        ListBox1.Items.Add(filename);
        folderPath = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(folderPath, @"\\", @"/"); //tried to do with and without this line
        Image1.ImageUrl = folderPath + filename;
```

Where is my fault? If I enter in address-line localhost\images\pic.jpg it's shown well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your file paths confused. [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) takes a relative path and gets a physical file path for that relative path. Images can't use this -- it should use the relative path.

Your code should look like this:

```
string relPath = String.Format("~/images/{0}", filename);
string filePath = Server.MapPath(relPath);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
ListBox1.Items.Add(filename);
Image1.ImageUrl = relPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = folderPath + filename;
```

at this point folderPath is something like c:/pathToApp/images/